# Compile a region in auctex with import package

Tags: emacs, auctex, import

Consider the three following (see below) files: `test.tex` is in the main directory, `test1.tex` is in the subdirectory `./test1/` and `test11.tex` is in the subsubdirectory `./test1/test11/` (see the directory structure below).

When I compile with auctex (`C-c C-c`) from the buffer where I read `test11.tex`, the file is compiled correctly: no problem. However, if I want to compile only the region (see screenshot below) where the figure environement is (`C-c C-r`), it fails. The `_region_.tex` produced by auctex in the directory where the master-file is is reproduced at the end of the question. This happens because no `import`-related command is issued in the `_region_.tex` file: thus the `graphicspath` is not adjusted. Is there a workaround?

Note: I can add the directory of the imported and subimported files in the `Local Variables` section it if can help.

[image: emacs screenshot]

```
├── _region_.aux
├── _region_.log
├── _region_.pdf
├── _region_.tex
├── test1
│   ├── test11
│   │   ├── KnuthAtOpenContentAlliance.jpg
│   │   ├── test11.log
│   │   └── test11.tex
│   └── test1.tex
├── test.aux
├── test.log
├── test.pdf
├── test-pics.pdf
└── test.tex
```

---

```
% This is ./test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{import}
\begin{document}

\import{./test1/}{test1.tex}

\end{document}
```

---

```
% This is ./test1/test1.tex
\subimport{test11/}{test11.tex}

% Local Variables:
% TeX-master: "../test.tex"
% End:
```

---

```
% This is ./test1/test11/test11.tex
% http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:KnuthAtOpenContentAlliance.jpg

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{KnuthAtOpenContentAlliance}
\end{figure}

Test...

% Local Variables:
% TeX-master: "../../test.tex"
% End:
```

---

This is the file `_region_.tex` produced by auctex.

```
\message{ !name(../../test.tex)}% This is ./test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{import}
\begin{document}

\message{ !name(test1/test11/test11.tex) !offset(-4) }
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{KnuthAtOpenContentAlliance}
\end{figure}

Test...

\message{ !name(../../test.tex) !offset(-7) }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the compilation fail, or you simply cannot view the image? If the former, can you send the contents of Emacs' output buffer? If the latter, did you check for resulting `_region_.pdf` in the master file directory?

Comment: @SašoŽivanović See my edited question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inspection of `_region_.tex` shows that it contains the information which file the region came from.

```
\message{ !name(test1/test11/test11.tex) !offset(-38) }
```

All we have to do is extract the path and fake it for `\includegraphics`. Thus, the plan:

1. Temporarily redefine `\message`.
2. Extract the path. (This is actually the hardest part ... I couldn't find any package doing it, so I used `pgfkeys`.)
3. Set whatever current-path macros `import` sets.
4. Make sure all this happens only if we're compiling a region. We don't want to end up with a redefined `\message`!

Point 4 is accomplished by setting AUCTeX's variable `TeX Command -> TeX Region Extra` to `\let\message\regioncompilationfix`.

And here's the code accomplishing the real work. (Only the master file needs to be changed.)

```
% This is ./test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{import}

\makeatletter
% 1. Temporarily redefine `\message`.
\let\regioncompilationfix@orig@message\message
\def\regioncompilationfix#1{%
  \let\message\regioncompilationfix@orig@message
  \message{#1}%
  \regioncompilationfix@parsemessage#1%
}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\regioncompilationfix@parsemessage\space!name(#1) !offset(#2) {%
  \getpath{#1}%
  % 3. Set whatever the `import` package sets.
  \edef\import@path{\getpathresult/}%
  \edef\Ginput@path{{\getpathresult/}{./}}%
  \edef\input@path{{\getpathresult/}{./}}%
}
% 2. Define a macro which extracts the path from path+filename.
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\def\getpath#1{%
  {%
    %\pgfkeyslet{/getpath/#1}\relax
    %\pgfkeyslet{/getpath/#1/.@cmd}\relax
    % to be really sure this worked, we'd also need to delete
    % key "/getpath/path/.unknown" ... but since we're searching for
    % the "path", we just hope nothing's there ...
    \pgfkeys{%
      /handlers/.unknown/.code={%
        \xdef\getpathresult{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}%(
        \expandafter\getpath@stripprefix\getpathresult)%
      },
      /getpath/#1,
    }%
  }%
}
\def\getpath@stripprefix/getpath/#1){\gdef\getpathresult{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\import{./test1/}{test1.tex}
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**: A purely AUCTeX way

AUXTeX provides hook `TeX-region-hook` which is run just after the region buffer is constructed. This is the Elisp code that inserts the TeX code that adjusts `import`'s paths:

```lisp
(add-hook 
 'TeX-region-hook 
 (lambda ()
   (goto-char (point-min))
   (search-forward "\\begin{document}")
   (insert
    "\\makeatletter"
    "\\def\\import@path{"
    (TeX-quote-filename (file-name-directory original))
    "}"
    "\\edef\\Ginput@path{{\\import@path}{./}}"
    "\\edef\\input@path{{\\import@path}{./}}"
    "\\makeatother"
    )
   )
 )
```

Put this code in your `.emacs` file.

Comment: Nice trick +1. However, I was hoping that one could configure auctex to change the content of `_region_.tex` to include the adapted `graphicspath`. I'd rather not change my `tex-master` file. Do you know by chance what piece of `lisp` code create the `_region_.tex` file and how to customize it?

Comment: I was writing an explanation why it cannot be done when I found `TeX-region-hook` ;-)  ---Btw, `_region_.tex` is created by function `TeX-region-create` in `tex-buf.el`.